# Read Kafka topic from beginning in KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

My spring boot project has an application that demonstrates Kafka Streams API. I am able to consume all the messages in topic `customer` using the command

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic customer  --from-beginning`

What's the similar command in Kafka Streams API to consume messages with KStream or KTable? I tried

`properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");`

Both didn't work. I did create a test case to consume with `KafkaConsumer` instead of Streams, it didn't work. Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing) for reference. Any help would be great.

Comment: Auto offset reset only applies if you lose your offset position for some reason. Have you tried using seek() or using the consumer group command line tool to change the offset position? Another thing to consider is why you are going back to the beginning. If it's just to start over clean, how about the streams reset tool or updating the application id to a new value? Lots of options here but you have to decide why you want to change the position.

Comment: I don’t think we can use seek method with streams api.

Comment: There were several other options besides this presented. Are that not what you need? Have you read https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/ ? Please be more specific.

Comment: I read that. It explains how to reset application.This is not something I am looking for. seek method is part of KafkaConsumer class. I am looking for seek method alternative in Kafka Streams API

Comment: The tool `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` allows to seek since v1.1, too. Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-171+-+Extend+Consumer+Group+Reset+Offset+for+Stream+Application

Comment: @dawsaw The reason why I am looking for this is " My use case joins customers and orders using Streams API. I send objects from the producer and consuming them using KStream and KTable". The problem is I am receiving customer object and order object at different times as expected. I am storing orders in the state store. When I send customer object again, it's not joining customer and order, instead, it's looking in a topic which is empty (not yet sent from the producer). So, I wanted to read order topic from the start when I receive customer object.

Comment: @dawsaw Code uploaded here https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing if you want to take a look

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax This helped me. Can you post this as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` allows to seek since v1.1.

Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-171+-+Extend+Consumer+Group+Reset+Offset+for+Stream+Application

Comment: Can I make that with programmatically?

Comment: KafkaStreams does not expose any API to seek. -- The app must be stopped to seek. Instead of using the command line tool, you could use a `KafkaConsumer` and commit the offsets you want to start from, and restart KafkaStreams afterward and it will pick up the committed offsets. (This is also what the command line tool does internally.)

Comment: I implemented above and it worked successfully.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995313/reset-consumer-offset-to-the-beginning-from-kafka-streams]
 
`StreamsResetter resetter = new StreamsResetter();`

`String[] args = {"--application-id", "omer-app-id2", "--bootstrap-servers",` 

`"kafka.dev.tbgth.k2.net:19092", "--input-topics", topicName};`

`resetter.run(args);`

However, i'm not sure its the correct solution.
I'm wondering about this solution has any side effect.

Comment: `StreamsResetter` is what the command line tool uses. -- Note though, that the class is not public API and there is no guarantee about backward compatibility in future releases.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I don't want to delete my state but just wanted to reprocess certain input topics. It seems application reset tool will delete the changelog topics. Currently we are running the command line tool to reset the offset of consumer group to beginning for specific topics. It is done as part of application deployment. However, we would like to make it part of application itself.

Comment: You could use a `KafkaConsumer`, `seekToBeginning` and `commit()` before you start `KafkaStreams`.