# How can I consume message in topic many times

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have producer which I call and posts a record to Kafka, then I call a consumer which returns the record, but when I call the consumer again the consumer doesn't return any records. (I need to get the record which I had posted to Kafka again). How can I do this?(Any code would be appreciated)

Comment: @STaefi but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka doesn't delete the message after it has been consumed. But it keeps the offset of reading for any consumer. So after you read a message from it, the offset goes forward. The second read doesn't read anything because the offset point after your only message and there is nothing after that. You should try resetting the offset before you read again. See this post:

[Reset consumer offset to the beginning from Kafka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995313/reset-consumer-offset-to-the-beginning-from-kafka-streams)

But if you don't want to reset locally or globally, you can create another consumer group and since every consumer group has its own offset, your second read by the new consumers can achieve what you want. See this link:

[kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html)

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't find any useful code there. I'm sending records of String, bye[]

Comment: try consuming with tow different consumer to consume the same message. Create two consumer objects and see whether this way you can consume the same message twice or not.

Comment: Updated answer to specify that **consumer groups** share offsets. New group is a new offset handling

Comment: Thanks for hint @cricket_007, an important point I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reset the offset to desired offset or if you need to consumer from the start offset ( whatever is available in kafka) , then you can set the consumer property "auto.offset.reset=earliest"

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide every time a new `group.id` value for the consumer properties. Just generate a random string value. The property `auto.offset.reset` must be set to `earliest`.

Comment: Do you have `auto.offset.reset` property as  `earliest`?